# Is it possible to access the Camera Remote API for DSC-QX10 and DSC-QX100 through 5ghz or wired (USB) connection?

Tags: camera, usb, sony

I'd like to use the QX10 or QX100 cameras, but unfortunately 2.4ghz is off the table.

The other options are:
 - usb cable
 - wifi A or AC connection over 5ghz

The https://developer.sony.com/devices/cameras/sony-smartphone-attachable-lens-style-camera-dsc-qx100/ doesn't specify , what kind of wifi these cams support.

Can I use the Camera Remote (or other) api to access the features of the camera through USB?

Can I connect to QX10 or QX100 via 5gz Wifi?

(I'd use linux to query the api, so no android or ios specific details matter.)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use Camera Remote API beta via USB. QX100 and QX10 support only 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: Is there a chance USB/AP support will be added later? Having to use 2 wifi adapters in PC is very inconvenient